# Differentiating between empty cell and 0 value in Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to differentiate between 0 & Empty cells in Google Sheets.
Im using an Appscripty to send out an email from a spreadsheet data using an HTML Message.

When I pull the values from the sheet, there are certain cells with 0 written in them and some are empty.

Both are getting written as 0 in the HTML message.
Can someone help?

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 3):

When you read values from a spreadsheet using `Range.getValue()` or `Range.getValues()`, blank cells are retrieved as a String, `""`.

In your code, you can simply check for blanks:

```
if (curVal === "") {
  // cell is blank
}
else {
  // not blank - handle value appropriately
}
```

Of course, you could just use `convertRange2html()` from the [SheetConverter library](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/sheetconverter).

Comment: Could it be a htmlencode issue? Null and zero should not be handled as the same, especially if they are both parsed as strings. "" vs "0"

Comment: @zwisch - without seeing the original source code, it's just a guess. Since null, a null string, and zero _should _ be treated differently, my guess would be that there is some code doing something silly like `Number(value)`, because `Number(null)` and `Number('')` both evaluate to `0`, and would explain the observed behaviour.

Comment: It is the use of the strict equality operator (===) in the above answer that solves the OP's issue, assuming the OP is using the result of Range.getValue() to compare to "" to determine a blank cell.  If the OP is using ==, then 0 in a sheet's cell is converted to "" during the evaluation of if (cellValue == ""), and that is why 0 equals "" for the OP's assumed code (making assumptions of course since OP did not provide any code).